# How to index all the unique words in the corpus using perl

Tags: perl, indexing

```
.i 1
.t
 effici machineindepend procedur 
garbag collect  variou list structur
.w
 method  return regist   free
list   essenti part   list process
system.   paper past solut   recoveri
problem  review  compar.  new algorithm
 present  offer signific advantag  speed
 storag util.  routin  implement
 algorithm   written   list languag 
       insur  degre
 machin independ. final  applic  
algorithm   number  differ list structur
appear   literatur  indic.
.b
cacm august 1967
.a
schorr h.
wait w. m.
.n
ca670806 jb februari 27 1978 428 pm
.x
1024 4 1549

1024 4 1549

1050 4 1549

.i 2
.t
 comparison  batch process  instant turnaround
.w
 studi   program effort  student
  introductori program cours  present
  effect  have instant turnaround   minut
 oppos  convent batch process
 turnaround time    hour  examin. 
 item compar   number  comput
run  trip   comput center program prepar
time keypunch time debug time
number  run  elaps time    run
   run   problem.   
result  influenc   fact  bonu point
 given  complet   program problem
    specifi number  run 
 evid  support instant  batch.
.b
cacm august 1967
.a
smith l. b.
.n
ca670805 jb februari 27 1978 432 pm
.x
1550 4 1550

1550 4 1550

1304 5 1550

1472 5 1550
```

Now the above text is the content of 2 files which is both stopped and stemmed, new file starts from .i (followed by a number) need to do indexing of the words in the text between .t & .b , .b & .a , .a & .n, .n &.x and ignore all text between .x and start of new document. i.e. .I (followed by a number)

The contents of all the files are stored in a single file say 'corpus'. need to do index all the unique words with how many times they appear in the corpus and in each document, may be at what positions in the documents.

```
open FILE, '<', 'sometext.txt' or die $!;
my @texts = <FILE>;
foreach my $text(@texts) {
        my @lines = split ("\n",$text);
        foreach my $line(@lines) {
            my @words = split (" ",$text);
            foreach my $word(@words) {
                $word = trim($word);
                my $match = qr/$word/i;

                open STFILE, '<', 'sometext.txt' or die $!;
                my $count=0;

                while (<STFILE>) {
                    if ($_ =~ $match) {
                        my @mword = split /\s+/, $_;
                        $_ =~ s/[A-Za-z0-9_ ]//g;
                        for my $i (0..$#mword) {
                            if ($mword[$i] =~ $match) {
                                #print "match found on line $. word ", $i+1,"\n";
                                $count++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                print "$word appears $count times \n";
                close(STFILE) or die "Couldn't close $file: $!\n\n";
            }
        }
    }


    close(FILE) or die "Couldn't close $file: $!\n\n";

    sub trim($)
{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

the above code counts the number of occurrence of each word in a corpus.
how to change it, so that it also counts the occurrence of word in individual document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

**edit** add distinct counter for each doc:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $words;
my $doc;
my $file = 'path/to/file';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading:$!"
while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $doc = $_ if /^\.i/;
    next if (/^\.x\b/ .. /^\.i\b/);
    next if /^\./;
    my @words = split;
    for(@words) {
        $words->{$_}{$doc}++;
    }
}
close $fh;
print Dumper $words;
```

Comment: The above code works fine with calculating the frequency of words, but i need to calculate the frequency of words in each document. for example:- "apple" appears 3 times in doc1 and 4 times in doc5 and 7 times in doc8. and so on...

Comment: i took the out of the above code in the file. But i want to use the values in the dumper, how to extract/access it?

Comment: @ArpitaDuppala: I don't really get what you mean. But to access the count a peculiar word within peculiar doc, ie: `print $words->{'.i 1'}{algorithm};` will print `3`

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash, with the hash value containing each word's current count. Loop over all the lines and all the words. Use a dumb (flag variable) based state machine for ignoring the text between .t and .b

If you get stuck on writing any of the above code, please post a specific question on what has you stuck.